# create javascript regular expression with numbers and carriage return

Tags: regex

I need to create a regular expression in javascript in order to parse an textarea input
something like that:

```
02192192932
23923929329
```

so there are only numbers  delimited by carriage return or/and newline

what is the right regex for this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to extract the numbers or are you trying to simply see if it matches an expected format?

Comment: How do you want to parse it? Read each line separately? Get the whole number?

Comment: i want to extract the exact value,and eliminate anything else in that input if this the input does not follow the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a neat trick to simplify the task:

```
/^\d+$/mg
```

That `m` modifier changes the behaviour of `^` and `$` to mean "start/end of *line*" as opposed to their original meaning "start/end of *subject*".

In particular, this handles alternate types of newline for you. Pretty neat!

Comment: @AmitJoki It's so rarely used that I had to double-check to see if it was a thing in JS :D

Comment: However, I did forget about the `g` modifier. Embarrassing. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

somebody told me to do something much complex like this
RegExp("^[0-9]+(\r?\n[0-9]+)*$") or RegExp("^[0-9]+(\r?\n[0-9]+)*$")